# DatePicker has to go back at the last Selected date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am working on a event calendar in which you can add an event.

When you are setting up a new event, you get a form. On this form, you can select a date with a datepicker.
Now when you click on submit, the form is empty again.

The datepicker has to go back to the last date you selected when you are on a new form.

I have got a few lines of code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#rst_datepicker').datepicker({
        //*minDate: 0, uitgeschakeld om de voorgaande datums te selecteren
        dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',
        date : jQuery('rst_event_date').val,
        //*jQuery('#rst_datepicker').datepicker('setDate', '01-12-2014');       
    }) //.datepicker("setDate", getDate);`
})
```

This is the form.

```
<h1>Evenementen toevoegen</h1><br />
    <form method="post" action="" id="rst_form_new_event">
        <i>Evenementnaam:</i><br />
        <input type="text" required class="required rst_admin_textbox"  name="rst_event_name" maxlength="40" value="<?php if (!empty($_POST['rst_event_name'])){echo $_POST[ 'rst_event_name'];} ?>" /><br /><br />
        <i>Datum:</i><br/>
        <input type="text" required class="required rst_admin_textbox"  id="rst_datepicker" name="rst_event_date" value="<?php if (!empty($_POST['rst_event_date'])){ $dateTimeReverse = new DateTime($_POST['rst_event_date']); $rst_event_date_reversed = date_format ($dateTimeReverse, 'd-m-Y'); echo $rst_datepicker; }else{$dateTimeReverse = new DateTime($val->rst_event_date); $rst_event_date_reversed = date_format ($dateTimeReverse, 'd-m-Y'); echo $rst_datepicker;}?> "  /><br /><br />
        <i>Dagdelen:</i><br /><br />
        <table id="rst_table_duties">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Begintijd
                </td>
                <td>
                    Eindtijd
                </td>
                <td>
                    Aantal personen
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="rst_session_from">
                    <input type="text" required class="required rst_timeentry rst_txt_session_from" name="rst_event_session[1][from]" maxlength="5"  />
                </td>
                <td  class="rst_session_to">  
                    <input type="text" required class="required rst_timeentry rst_txt_session_to" name="rst_event_session[1][to]" maxlength="5"  />
                </td>
                <td class="rst_event_amount_duties">
                    <select name="rst_event_session[1][duties_amount]">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>

                    </select>
                </td>
                <td class="rst_session_remove"><a href="#" class="rst_remove_session_row">-</a></td><td>(wissen)</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <a href="#" id="rst_add_session_row">Nieuw dagdeel toevoegen</a><br /><br />
        <i>Informatie:</i><br />
        <textarea class="rst_admin_textarea" name="rst_event_info" spellcheck="true"><?php if (!empty($_POST['rst_event_info'])){echo $_POST[ 'rst_event_info'];} ?></textarea><br />
        <input type="submit" name="rst_add_event" value="Evenement bevestigen"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: Does your form invoke default behaviour? I.E: Does it reload the page?

Comment: This `jQuery('rst_event_date')` is meaningless. maybe you mean: `jQuery('#rst_event_date')` ?

Comment: It does reload the page

Comment: oh btw i didnt made the whole script i only get to edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are submitting on the same page then you will get the `$_REQUEST` variable. You can use that to set the value

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#rst_datepicker').datepicker({
        //*minDate: 0, uitgeschakeld om de voorgaande datums te selecteren
        dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',
        date : "<?php echo $_REQUEST['rst_event_date']; ?>",
        //*jQuery('#rst_datepicker').datepicker('setDate', '01-12-2014');       
    }) //.datepicker("setDate", getDate);`
})
```

Comment: You forgot quotes for your date

Comment: It doesnt do anything